# determine duplicate rows whose at least one row has different value in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to find duplicate rows where for a column not all of them have the same value.

```
   SAMPN     PERNO    loop    mode1    mode2   
    1         1         1        1       2      
    1         1         1        1       2       
    1         1         1        1       2      
    1         1         1        1       2      
    1         2         1        1       1        
    1         2         1        1       1        
    1         2         1        1       3      
    2         2         2        3       1       
    2         2         2        3       2        
    2         2         2        3       3
```

I want to find duplicate rows in columns `SAMPN     PERNO    loop    mode1` which at lease one of them has different value in `mode2`.

output

```
   SAMPN     PERNO    loop    mode1    mode2    
    1         2         1        1       1        
    1         2         1        1       1        
    1         2         1        1       3      
    2         2         2        3       1       
    2         2         2        3       2        
    2         2         2        3       3
```

Comment: `df %>%
  group_by(SAMPN, PERNO, loop, mode1) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(mode2) > 1)
`

Comment: @kath right I can remove duplicate rows

Comment: @sara I think I understand now what you mean...